# How to use viewJsonService with xp:repeat control

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Okay, there is a good description how to use the viewJsonService REST service with the Dojo Data Grid control (Brad Balassaitis)

But how can/should I use it with the Repeat control (xp:repeat) alternative Data Table ?

Comment: The `viewJsonService` is designed to interact with front-end components (i.e. JavaScript widgets making AJAX calls to retrieve the JSON from the service). Repeat controls are back-end controls that are typically just bound directly to a data source or other server-side abstraction layer. What's your use case?

Comment: no use case, just exploring the options